# Minificar Js con Gulp

Tags: javascript, css3, scss, gulp, gulp-sass

estoy minificando mis archivos css y js con gulp

Js

```
gulp.task('jsTask', function () {
    return src('src/assets/js/*/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'));
});
```

me funciona correctamente, pero que lo que deseo es que si hay carpetas me meta esos archivos en carpetas separadas, justo como sucede con el css.

Css

```
gulp.task('sass', ()=>
    gulp.src('src/assets/scss/*/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'))
);
```

Carpetas Css Minificado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Carpetas Css Js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, no quiero que todos los archivos de Js se me compilen en uno solo, lo hago así para separar funciones por cada página del sitio.